# Apache Zookeeper service not running and exiting abnormally on Ubuntu 20.04.5

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, virtual-machine, apache-zookeeper, systemctl

I am trying to run Kafka zookeeper service using 'sudo systemctl start zookeeper' command on Ubuntu VM. On checking status, zookeeper service is not running, and it is throwing exception.

This is the path where zookeeper and Kafka service are present.
/etc/systemd/system

My zookeeper service:

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /kafka/config/zookeeper.properties 
ExecStop=/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My kafka service:

```
[Unit]
Requires=zookeeper.service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /kafka/config/server.properties
ExecStop=/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On running zookeeper and Kafka services using 'sudo systemctl', I am facing exception:

[Zookeeper service] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MijJ3.png)

[Kafka service] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDj8v.png)

Link I have followed to install and run kafka service on Ubuntu is:
https://hevodata.com/blog/how-to-install-kafka-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://hevodata.com/blog/how-to-install-kafka-on-ubuntu/, this is the link I have followed to install and run Kafka on Ubuntu, but my zookeeper and Kafka services are not running.

Comment: Typo? Zookeeper doesn't run on 5181, so you have configured your files incorrectly